# List bindings for an exchange with rabbitmq java client API

Tags: java, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I can't seem to find any information in the documentation so I was wondering if it was somehow possible to get all the bindings related to an exchange using the java RabbitMQ API.

I'm looking for something like the http api result when querying /api/bindings.

Comment: If by java RabbitMQ API you mean the Java AMQP client, then no. Bindings can only be listed via the management plugin, or by running rabbitmqctl on the command line. Of course you can write a Java library for querying the HTTP API

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`/api/definitions` is the API endpoint to get list of definitions including exchanges, queues, bindings, users, virtual hosts, permissions and parameters.

https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/