# Is there a way to get all headers bound to a queue from an Amqp 0.9.1 RabbitMq broker using the java client?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

Using com.rabbitmq.client with AMQP version 0.9.1 I am doing the following to declare a durable headers exchange, declare a durable queue, and bind the queue to the exchange with headers.

```
channel.exchangeDeclare("myExchange", "headers", true);
channel.queueDeclare("myQueue", true, false, false, null);

Map<String, Object> bindingArgs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
bindingArgs.put("x-match", "any"); //any or all
bindingArgs.put("headerName1", "headerValue1");

channel.queueBind("myQueue", "myExchange", "", bindingArgs);
```

If I run the same code again, but with a different header name/value I am effectively adding another header to the queue on the broker (not replacing the previous one).

i.e.

```
...
bindingArgs.put("headerName2", "headerValue2");
...
```

Is there a way with the java rabbitmq client to get all of the bound headers for a queue from the broker?

This would return something like:

```
"headerName1" : "headerValue1"
"headerName2" : "headerValue2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of

[List bindings for an exchange with rabbitmq java client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988440/list-bindings-for-an-exchange-with-rabbitmq-java-client-api).

While this functionality doesn't appear to be in the java client, it is possible to view bindings (including header arguments) via command line on the broker.

```
rabbitmqctl list_bindings
```

See the RabbitMQ documentation for more options
https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#list_bindings